# Memory access violation. What's wrong with this seemingly simple program?

Tags: c

This is a quick program I just wrote up to see if I even remembered how to start a c++ program from scratch.  It's just reversing a string (in place), and looks generally correct to me.  Why doesn't this work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void strReverse(char *original)
{
    char temp;
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(original) - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        temp = original[i];
        original[i] = original[j];
        original[j] = temp;
    }
}

void main()
{
    char *someString = "Hi there, I'm bad at this.";
    strReverse(someString);

}
```

Comment: As sbi's answer shows, you can do this much simpler using the C++ standard library. If, for some reason, you prefer sticking to C functions as your own code does, perhaps you should retag the question as C instead.

Comment: Retagged the question, Mark is obviously aiming for a C implementation here.

Comment: He is using namespaces and including a C++ header though.

Comment: Now that you mention it, i should have tagged this as C.  I'm aiming to avoid libraries for basic things like this :)  Thanks

Comment: Why? It's what they're for. And `strlen` is as much as library function as `std::reverse` is.

Comment: Using libraries when they are available is almost always the smarter thing to do. Also, if it's such a basic thing, then why did you need help from the SO community? On top of that, strlen() is a library function...

Comment: Argh, don't people even search before asking a question.  This same question has been asked and answered a half dozen times in the last week or so.

Comment: @mizipzor: How can a question coming with code containing `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` be tagged `C` at all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you change this, which makes `someString` a pointer to a read-only string literal:

```
char *someString = "Hi there, I'm bad at this.";
```

to this, which makes `someString` a modifiable array of `char`, *initialized* from a string literal:

```
char someString[] = "Hi there, I'm bad at this.";
```

You should have better results.

While the type of `someString` in the original code (`char*`) allows modification to the `char`s that it points to, because it was actually pointing at a string literal (which are not permitted to be modified) attempting to do any modification through the pointer resulted in what is technically known as *undefined behaviour*, which in your case was a memory access violation.

Answer (score 11):

If this isn't homework, the C++ tag demands you do this by using the C++ standard library:

```
std::string s("This is easier.");
std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
```

Oh, and it's `int main()`, always `int main()`, dammit!

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to modify a string literal - a string allocated in static storage. That's undefiend behaviour (usually crashes the program).

You should allocate memory and copy the string literal there prior to reversing, for example:

```
char *someString = "Hi there, I'm bad at this.";
char* stringCopy = new char[strlen( someString ) + 1];
strcpy( stringCopy, someString );
strReverse( stringCopy );
delete[] stringCopy;//deallocate the copy when no longer needed
```

Comment: Personally, I'd use strdup, but I'm oldschool.

Comment: strdup() is nice, but it requires using free() and using free(0 is not considered good C++, but rather oldschool C. Otherwise I'd also prefer strdup().

Comment: So what's the difference?  Is it that i'm giving it its value on declaration?  If I had left it as char *someString; and then passed user input to it, I could perform the operation?

Comment: The key is how the memory is allocated. If it is heap- or stack-allocated, it is allright. In origonal code it is allocated statically when the program is started and marked read-only, so writing to it is prohibited.

Comment: As @sharptooth said, you've declared that "somestring" is a pointer to the literal string - ie. it's pointing to some storage that is part of the program code, and therefore not modifiable.  You have to put it in modifiable memory in order to reverse it.

Comment: @sharptooth: Why did you introduce dynamically allocated strings anyway? What's wrong with a simple `char someString[] = "Hi there, I'm bad at this."`?

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
char *someString = "Hi there, I'm bad at this.";
```

makes `someString` point to a string literal, which cannot be modified. Instead of using a raw pointer, use a character array:

```
char someString[] = "Hi there, I'm bad at this.";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change string literals (staticly allocated). To do what you want, you need to use something like:

```
int main()
{
    char *str = new char[a_value];
    sprintf(str, "%s", <your string here>);
    strReverse(str);
    delete [] str;
    return 0;
}
```

[edit] strdup also works, also strncpy... i'm sure there's a variety of other methods :)

Comment: Just asked this question to the person above and then read your answer :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See sharptooth for explanation.

Try this instead:

```
#include <cstring>

void main()
{
    char someString[27];
    std::strcpy( someString, "Hi there, I'm bad at this." );
    strReverse( someString );
}
```

Better yet, forget about `char *` and use `<string>` instead. This is C++, not C, after all.

Answer (score 0):

When using more strict compiler settings, this code shouldn't even compile:

```
char* str = "Constant string";
```

because it should be constant:

```
const char* str = "Now correct";
const char str[] = "Also correct";
```

This allows you to catch these errors faster. Or you can just use a character array:

```
char str[] = "You can write to me, but don't try to write something longer!";
```

To be perfectly safe, just use std::string. You're using C++ after all, and raw string manipulation is extremely error-prone.

Comment: Actually it has to compile. For compatibility, there's a conversion from `const char[]` to `char*`. It's deprecated and you shouldn't sue it, but it's (still) part of the standard.

Comment: No, `char* str = "Constant string"` **must** compile. 4.2/2 says that a string literal that is not a wide string literal can be coverted to an rvalue of tpy "pointer to `char`". A conforming compiler cannot reject this initialization.

Comment: Thanks, I made my post more accurate - it's about compiler settings (which you can set to be more strict than the standard is).

Comment: If you say "You're using C++ after all", I don't think that you can really say "shouldn't even compile" when referring to strictly conforming code. You could say that you can _ask_ a compiler to reject this otherwise conforming code, but I saying that it *should* reject it is too strong (IMHO).

Comment: there's no such thing as "more strict than the standard is", since the strictness is determined by how closely it enforces the standard.